# Excepctions в WebClient

Tags: c#

Необходимо, чтобы при недоступности сайта/отсутствии файла не выбрасывало Exception, а просто отображался текст, который в catch

```
try
{
    Version currentVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
    WebClient http = new WebClient();
    Version latestVersion = new Version(http.DownloadString("http://kottsov.ru/ver.txt"));
    if (latestVersion > currentVersion)
    {
        label3.Text = "Текущая версия: " + Application.ProductVersion + " (устаревшая, посетите сайт для обновления)";
    }
    else label3.Text = "Текущая версия: " + Application.ProductVersion + " (актуальная)";
}
catch (System.IO.IOException e) label3.Text = "Текущая версия: " + Application.ProductVersion;
```

По идее, должно получиться так, что программа берет из .txt файла на сайте актуальную версию программы, сравнивает со своей и, если она устарела, меняет текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы обратитесь к [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) по методу `DownloadString`, то увидите, что этот метод может выбросить следующие типы исключений:

- `ArgumentNullException`
- `WebException`
- `NotSupportedException`

Вам нужен `WebException` -- исключение именно такого типа выбрасывается, если запрошенный ресурс недоступен. Поэтому в `catch` блоке вам надо ловить не `IOException`, а `WebException`:

```
catch (System.Net.WebException)
{
    label3.Text = "Текущая версия: " + Application.ProductVersion;
}
```